# .netcore upgrade from to 2.1 to 3.1 issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am upgrading a serverless hybrid mobile application from .net-core 2.1 to .net-core 3.1 but I am encountering this error:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.: TypeInitializationException
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..ctor()
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor(Boolean useSocketsHttpHandler)    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler..ctor()
at NTLMWrapperv2.Handler.Get(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in D:\a\1\s\Handler.cs:line 113
at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )
at Interop.Http.GetSupportedFeatures()
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..cctor() The type initializer for 'HttpInitializer' threw an exception.: TypeInitializationException
at Interop.Http..cctor() Unable to load shared library 'System.Net.Http.Native' or one of its dependencies.
   In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the
   LD_DEBUG environment variable: libSystem.Net.Http.Native: cannot
   open shared object file: No such file or directory: 
   DllNotFoundException
at Interop.Http.GetSslVersionDescription()
at Interop.HttpInitializer..cctor()
```

The error appears to be on this line of code:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler {​​​​​ Credentials = cc }​​​​​)
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
```

When I read the breaking changes for .net-core 3.0 or 3.1 there seems to be no sign of change for the HttpClientHandler code. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered upgrading all the referenced packages as well ?

Comment: Yes I updated all the referenced packages.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. :(